# Converting worded date format to datetime format in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Today one of my script gave an error for an invalid datetime format as an input. The script is expecting the datetime input as '%m/%d/%Y', but it got it in an entirely different format. For example, the date should have been 5/2/2022 but it was May 2, 2022. To add a bit more information for clarity, the input is coming for a Google sheet and the entire date is in a single cell (rather than different cells for month, date and year).

Is there a way to convert this kind of worded format to the desired datetime format before the script starts any kind of processing?

Comment: Is this a constant format May 2, 2022 or is it someone put the data into the data source in an incorrect format?

Comment: Month is abbreviated or is it a full name?

Comment: I believe it is abbreviated. However it is hard to say because it only happened for the month of May so far. I wasn't aware of %B so that's definitely helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're in presence of the full month name, try this:

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(df["Date"], format="%B %d, %Y")
0   2022-05-02
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

According to the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes):

- `%B`: "Month as locale’s full name".
- `%d`: "Day of the month as a zero-padded decimal number". (Although it seems to work in this case)
- `%Y`: "Year with century as a decimal number."

Now, if you want to transform this date to the format you initially expected, just transform the series using `.dt.strftime`:

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(df["Date"], format="%B %d, %Y").dt.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
0    05/02/2022
Name: Date, dtype: object
```